# How to encode password with single and double quotes using base64_encode

Tags: php, drupal, base64, authorization

I'm calling an API using Postman, It requires Authorization Type as Basic Auth,
Following are the modified credential for demonstration purpose,
Now in postman generate code snippet, it is showing Header as

```
'Authorization' => 'Basic ZHBjMzpXRWMzXCciSw==',
```

But when I do that using my code, the base64 encoded string is different and hence result in unauthorized user.

```
$username="dpc3";
$psd = 'WEc3\'"K'; // Added one \ before single quote
$credentials = base64_encode($username . ':' . $psd)
```

Using the above code the headers are

```
'Authorization' => 'Basic ZHBjMzpXRWMzJyJL'
```

this encoded string is different than what is there in postman. Postman API is working, but it's not working in code. Maybe I'm incorrectly encoding it. I have added password without any slash in postman. `WEc3'"K`

ANy help is much appreciated. Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

if you perform `base64_decode('ZHBjMzpXRWMzXCciSw==')` it will give you `dpc3:WEc3\'"K`

That means the back slash is actually added into the password.

So the correct string will be:

```
$username="dpc3";
$psd = 'WEc3\\\'"K'; // One backslash and one single quote - both escaped
$credentials = base64_encode($username . ':' . $psd); // ZHBjMzpXRWMzXCciSw==
```

Comment: What if a password contains some slashes by itself ???

Answer (score 2):

### Solution 1

The simplest way is to use [stripslashes](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.stripslashes.php) function like this:

```
$username = 'dpc3';
$psd = 'WEc3\'"K'; // Added one \ before single quote
$credentials = base64_encode($username . ':' . stripslashes($psd));
```

### solution 2

Or you could simply replace any `\'` within the password with a single `'` and pass it to the base64_encode() function like this:

```
$username = 'dpc3';
$psd = 'WEc3\'"K'; // Added one \ before single quote
$credentials = base64_encode($username . ':' . str_replace('\'', "'", $psd));
```

for more info on str_replace() check [this](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.str-replace.php)